# No javascript response

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why but this simple code is giving me no response
:

```js
function funcs() {
  document.getElementById("big").display = "none";
}
```

```html
<p id="big"> I am big</p>
<button onclick="funcs()">dissapear</button>
```

This is supposed to make the paragraph with id `big` disapear when the button is  clicked.

Comment: the button is supposed to make the paragraph with id "big'" dissapear onclicked

Answer (score 4):

You must add `style` here:

```
document.getElementById("big").style.display="none";
```